# How to handle very long running processes in NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus to handle some asynchronous tasks. Occasionally I have a task where I need to process 10,000 records, so this takes a few hours.

My problem is that when I handle these records all together, I cannot use NServiceBus default transaction handling.

Also - if I split these records up into 10,000 smaller messages, they will clog up MSMQ for a few hours, and users who are expecting functions to take a few minutes, will be waiting hours.

Is there a way in NServiceBus to prioritise different messages?

Comment: Typically one should steer clear of message priority.  Rather use priority / background queues.  So same code but different endpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd consider breaking it down into smaller batches (not necessarily one message per record) and having a separate endpoint service specifically for this process so that other stuff is not held up. If breaking it into batches and you care about the when they all complete then I'd recommend using a saga to track that state.

Comment: This might be useful to read: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/02/27/reducing-nservicebus-saga-load/